# Functions operating on arbitrary array sizes in Fortran

Tags: fortran

In Fortran 95, how would you write a function which takes an arbitrary matrix of known dimension as a argument ? I get the impression that not allocating the dimension doesn't work, even if the function only operates on matrices which have been previously allocated.

```
 real, dimension (2, 4) :: mymatrix
 test(mymatrix)
contains
 function test(matrix)
  real, dimension (: , :), intent(in) :: matrix
  someothervariable = matrix(i, j)
  return
 end function test(matrix)
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem (except the use of `test(mymatrix)` as a naked expression).  What is wrong with the approach here: do you get any complaints from the compiler.  [You also haven't any allocatable arrays.]

Answer (score 1):

This works as long as you have an explicit interface.  Putting the function as an internal procedure as you have it works, as does putting the procedure into a module.  Consider this example:

```
program example
  implicit none

  real, dimension(2,4) :: matrixA
  real, dimension(5,13) :: matrixB
  integer :: matval

  matval = test(matrixA)
  print *, 'Test returned: ',matval
  matval = test(matrixB)
  print *, 'Test returned: ',matval

contains

function test(matrix)
  implicit none
  real, dimension(:,:), intent(in) :: matrix
  integer :: test

  print *, "matrix dimensions:"
  print *, "i: ", lbound(matrix,1), ubound(matrix,1)
  print *, "j: ", lbound(matrix,2), ubound(matrix,2)
  test = ubound(matrix,1)*ubound(matrix,2)
end function test

end program example
```

The output of this program is:

```
 matrix dimensions:
 i:            1           2
 j:            1           4
 Test returned:            8
 matrix dimensions:
 i:            1           5
 j:            1          13
 Test returned:           65
```

You can see that none of the arrays are allocatable and arbitrary sized arrays can be passed to the function.  The function is able to inspect the bounds of the array dimensions and can operate on the contents of the array.  I had the function return a value based upon the array dimensions as an example.

---

The problems with your code fragment are that you are calling the function improperly and are not returning a value.  Functions (in Fortran) must return values and the value must be assigned to a variable.  See the differences in how I call the function in my example.  If you do not want to return a value, use a subroutine instead of a function.

Comment: Actually, the original form in the question with the internal procedure should work too.

Comment: The function `test` is an internal function of whatever fragment is offered in the question.  If we ignore the bad-call then an explicit interface is already available.

Comment: @VladimirF as it does (I missed my morning coffee...).  I modified the answer to use an internal procedure and just mention that it works in modules as well.

Comment: @francescalus I've modified my example and called out the improper function call.